# Suggest a change in tags when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Quite often when browsing through [elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir) questions I find myself editing [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix) to be [phoenix-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework). I have not (yet) come across a question that was truly meant to have the [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix) tag.

It would be great if upon submission of a question, the system could see that there were a number of edits from [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) -> [bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bar) and ask the user if they actually meant to use [bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bar) instead based on other tags that were used in the question.

Comment: the system already suggests certain tags

Comment: You mean if _truly meant to use foo_, right?

Comment: Sorry. I did word that poorly. Essentially yes. It would be nice if it would, from my specific example above, suggest using phoenix-framework over the selected phoenix tag.

Comment: Maybe changing phoenix to hadoop-phoenix would help.

Comment: SO has the same problem with `flex`, `flex-lexer`, and `flexbox`.  Flexbox questions are more common, but the `flex` tag was created for Adobe Flex.  Now if only we could get people to read the tag summaries...

Comment: We get a few `[server-side-events]` questions every week mis-tagged with `[sse]` (x86 SIMD).  Good idea to look at the other tags as a heuristic for the tag being inappropriate, that would catch essentially all of them, because `[javascript]` + `[sse]` is extremely rare.  (There's AFAIK still no well-supported way to use SIMD from JS, or to even give auto-vectorization hints.)

Comment: Not to mention `asp.net` with `model-view-controller` (which is a synonym for `mvc`). The trick here is that machine learning has to be taught, and it needs to be taught with good data. There is little to be had in tags :(.